# How to split a string column into multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with one string column and I'd like to split it into multiple columns by seperate with
**','**. I want to name the column as same as the string in the column before **':'**.

The column looks like this:

```
0  {"ID":"AP001","Name":"Anderson","Age":"23"}
1  {"ID":"AP002","Name":"Jasmine","Age":"36"} 
2  {"ID":"AP003","Name":"Zack","Age":"28"}
3  {"ID":"AP004","Name":"Chole","Age":"39"}
```

And I want to split to this:

| ID | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AP001 | Anderson | 23 |
| AP002 | Jasmine | 36 |
| AP003 | Zack | 28 |
| AP004 | Chole | 39 |

I have tried to split it by **','**, but im not sure how to remove the string before **':'** and put it as the column name.

```
data1 = data['demographic'].str.split(',',expand=True)
```

This is what I get after splitting it:

| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "ID":"AP001" | "Name":"Anderson" | "Age":"23" |
| "ID":"AP002" | "Name":"Jasmine" | "Age":"36" |
| "ID":"AP003" | "Name":"Zack" | "Age":"28" |
| "ID":"AP004" | "Name":"Chole" | "Age":"39" |

Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

data1 = pd.json_normalize(data['demographic'].apply(ast.literal_eval))
print(data1)

# Output
      ID      Name Age
0  AP001  Anderson  23
1  AP002   Jasmine  36
2  AP003      Zack  28
3  AP004     Chole  39
```